# Как "принять" сообщение с командой строки (bash) программой?

Tags: linux, c, bash, debian

Как "принять" сообщение с командой строки (bash) программой ? 
Я не совсем понимаю как правильно сформировать заголовок , но увидел такой вариант "Bash парсинг результата команды в си " возможно будет вернее.

В общем моя программа написана на си и она проста , 
С помощью команды `system` , я запускаю утилиты и команды, линуксе через командную строку, к примеру :

```
system("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000");
system("ip link set can0 up");
```

но если  КАН уже будет "поднят", то `bash` ответит мне

```
system("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000");
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
```

понятное дело что я как человек вижу сообщение и спокойно в ввожу команду `ip link set can0 down`, но хотелось бы чтоб программа понимала что КАН "поднят" надо его закрыть и снова поднять. Всё могу, кроме того чтобы программа "прочла" предупреждающее сообщение.

---

Воспользовался `popen` -ом :3

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
        FILE *read_fp;
        char buffer[BUFSIZ+1];
        int chars_read;
        memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));

        read_fp = popen("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000");
        if(chars_read > 0){
                printf("new soedinenie");
        }
        if(chars_read != 0){
                system("ip link set can0 down");
                system("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000");
        }
        pclose("read_fp");
        system("ip link set can0 up");

        printf("candump can0");
        system("candump can0");

        return 0;
}
```

Вот такой мне печальный ответ дала машина ;_; (полный попен).

```
root@R2CPU:/kononov# gcc -c exp_popen.c -o exp_popen.o
exp_popen.c: In function 'main':
exp_popen.c:13:12: error: too few arguments to function 'popen'
  read_fp = popen("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000");
            ^~~~~
In file included from exp_popen.c:3:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:874:14: note: declared here
 extern FILE *popen (const char *__command, const char *__modes) __wur;
              ^~~~~
exp_popen.c:21:9: warning: passing argument 1 of 'pclose' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  pclose("read_fp");
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from exp_popen.c:3:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:880:12: note: expected 'FILE * {aka struct _IO_FILE *}' but argument is of type 'char *'
 extern int pclose (FILE *__stream);
            ^~~~~~
```

Comment: Проверяй код возврата

Comment: Использовать [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)?

Comment: Вместо `system()` лучше использовать `popen()` и разбирать вывод. Только учтите, что обычно сообщения об ошибках утилиты пишут в stderr и тогда надо вызывать popen как-то так: `FILE *p = popen("prog args 2>&1", "r");`

Comment: @ Harry много слоффф не могу понять как отдельный поток мне поможет ??? по сути я даже не понял причём он вообще

Comment: @avp зачем мне файл ??? Зачем мне в файл считывать в отдельный поток, когда мне надо просто **принять** сообщение от компьютера и обработать всё

Comment: @timob256, тогда уж, для начала прочтите [man popen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen). Если же вам в самом деле достаточно только *кода возврата команды*, то в вызове `system()` просто перенаправьте весь вывод (вместе с stderr) в **/dev/null**

Comment: Ну так вызывайте `popen("строка","r")` - ну как и `fopen`. А в `pclose` передавайте не строку, а файловую переменную.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @Harry и @avp.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
        FILE *read_fp;
        char buffer[BUFSIZ+1];
        int chars_read;
        memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));

        read_fp = popen("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000", "r");
        if(read_fp != NULL){
                chars_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFSIZ, read_fp);
                printf("new soedinenie"); // printf почему то не выводит в баше 
           if(chars_read > 0){
                   printf("mi tyt");
                   system("ip link set can0 down");
                   system("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000");
           }
        }
        pclose(read_fp);
        system("ip link set can0 up");

        printf("candump can0");
        system("candump can0");

        return 0;
}
```

Всё работает, но почему то выводит цитату.

> RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy

и не работает `printf()` не выводит в баш но **основную функцию код выполняет :3**

Comment: В любом случае перенесите `pclose` внутрь `if(read_fp != NULL){ ... }` / Странно, что `printf` ничего не выводит, попробуйте добавить  `\n` в вывод. / Ну, у себя больше проверить не могу, т.к., естественно:  `Cannot find device "can0"` и `sh: 1: candump: not found` / Что касается `RTNETLINK....`, то могу предположить, что программу надо запускать от root / Кстати, я бы печатал для отладки коды возврата, которые возвращает `system`